# How to partition using custom partitioner within each partition?

Tags: apache-flink

I want to partition my data using custom partitioner and cross my DataSet with itself to produce a Cartesian product of my data within each partition.

Following code runs cross operator over all DataSet, but I'm looking for a solution to do so per and within partition.

```
DataSet<Tuple2<Integer, String>> partitionedData =
                data.partitionCustom(new MyPartitioner(), 0);

DataSet<Tuple2<Tuple2<Integer, String>, Tuple2<Integer, String>>> crossedData = data.cross(data);
```

Comment: `cross` will always compute the cross operation over the complete `DataSet`. You could compute the partial cross within a `mapPartition` operation where you perform the cross yourself or you assign a partition specific identifier to each element and join on this field.